# LC-3 PC-relative offset

Tags: lc3

Can someone explain if my reasoning is right?

The book gives the following question

Question: If a control instruction is in location 5, what is the PC-relative offset of address 15? Assume that the control transfer instructions work the same way as in the LC-3.

Answer: The incremented PC is 6. This means that the PC-relative offset of address 15 is 15-6=9.

Is it because since it is in location 5,and since the PC is incremented every instruction cycle that the PC is 6? and then do I just subtract to find the PC-relative offset of a given address?

the following question after that gives something familiar, I want to know if my reasoning is correct, that I know how to do the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. If the check instruction is at memory location 5, by the time you get to it the PC is already set to be on location 6. So you have to add something to it, that will take it to memory location 15, which is 9. I suggest translating the hex values in the simulator into binary and checking the PC offset bits on the instructions that have PC offset. It will help you better understand what's going on.